# Inquiry about Virtualization Support and HAXM Installation Issue on Intel Core i3-1115G4 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, hyper-v, haxm

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I'm experiencing an issue related to virtualization support and the installation of Intel HAXM on my system with an 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1115G4 processor. I'm hoping to gain insights and assistance from you.

Problem Details:

- Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1115G4 @ 3.00GHz
- Clock Speed: 3.00 GHz
- Virtualization Support (VT-X): Enabled in BIOS
- Operating System: Windows 11 Home Single Language, Version 22H2
- Issue: I'm facing difficulties installing the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) while installing components from Android Studio.

I have verified that virtualization support (VT-X) has been enabled in the BIOS. However, when I attempt to install HAXM during the Android Studio installation process, I receive an error message indicating that the system requirements are not met, halting the HAXM installation.

I'd like to understand if the 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1115G4 processor should indeed support virtualization or VT-X, and if so, why I'm encountering this issue when trying to install HAXM. Are there any specific steps or configurations I need to be aware of? I'm keen on utilizing HAXM for emulation purposes in Android Studio, and any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

The following message appears when the HAXM installation fails in the SDK Component Installer:

```
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) v.7.6.5".
Warning: Package "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager) should be installed in 
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" but 
it already exists.
Installing in "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2" instead.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_6_5.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) v.7.6.5" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) v.7.6.5" complete.
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) v.7.6.5" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\34.0.0\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2\package.xml
Warning: Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2' (Expected 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager')
Warning: Already observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager-2'
Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installation failed!
For more details, please check the installation log: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_install-20230815_2030.log
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows
Done
```

Error message :

```
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installation failed!
For more details, please check the installation log: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_install-20230815_2030.log
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows
Done
```

More details on the installation log: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_install-20230815_2030.log:

```
Version: 7.6.5
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM
Extract: checktool.exe... 100%
Execute: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM\checktool.exe --verbose
CPU vendor          *  GenuineIntel
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       -  No
VMX enabled         -  No
EPT supported       -  No
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    -  No
OS version          *  Windows 10.0.22621
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)
The system requirements are not satisfied.
```

Thank you for your time and understanding of this matter. I look forward to gaining useful guidance and advice from this community.

Thank you,
Osama

I have checked the information in the BIOS: [BIOS Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvQBG.jpg)

i have checked Virtualization on cmd (systeminfo) :

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

I have tried installing it manually from GitHub https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases ,
[Then a message appears...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Lha.png)

Comment: Windows 11 has usually Hyper-V enabled by default, which is incompatible with Haxm. Haxm is discontinued by Intel anyway. So uninstall Haxm and just use emulator without.